# Token CRSF with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using a script for generat token with link of website but i have always problem with the first refresh the next time all is good

```
session_start();
$link = 'http://localhost/';
$id_user = '123456789';

function getToken($name = '', $key)
{
    session_start();
    $token = sha1(uniqid());
    $_SESSION[$name.'_token'] = $token;
    return $token;
}


function checkToken($name = '', $post)
{
    session_start();
    global $link, $id_user;

    if(isset($_SESSION[$name.'_token']) && isset($_POST[$post]))
    {
        if(sha1($link.$id_user.$_SESSION[$name.'_token']) == $_POST[$post])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

First i create new token if empty or is not ajax call 
I use link, id user and unique token for verify is good or noot

```
if(empty($_SESSION['new_token']) || !$_REQUEST['ajax'] AND empty($_POST)) {
    $tokenUnique = sha1($link.$id_user.getToken('new'));
} else {
    $tokenUnique = sha1($link.$id_user.$_SESSION['new_token']);
}
```

And in ajax post i use this for view if checkToken is good

```
if(checkToken('new', 'token_hidden') == false) {
   die('error token');
}

<input type="hidden" name="token_hidden" value="<?=$tokenUnique?>" />
```

U have solution for secure ajax or complet my code ? 
Thanks

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $(div).serialize(),
    url: 'file.php?ajax=1',
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My code dont work always i have different token if i refresh website with F5 but after ajax call its work i need to generat new token in each F5 refresh but not change after ajax

Comment: Post the code of your ajax call

Comment: Its simple jquery code ajax work perfectly its just token not identic if i refresh page with F5 (i have add code in my first post)